# Activate Window and Send Input using SetForegroundWindow and SendKeys in C#

Tags: c#, input, sendkeys, setforegroundwindow

What I'm trying to do is activate another application and send a key input to it to trigger a button. However this code doesn't seem to work. It looks like it can find the application but it does not activate it, and does not send the key.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private void debugButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //GetProcess by Class
        IntPtr rightNowHandle = FindWindow("WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.24dc298_r17_ad2", null);
        //Get Handle by Process
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("RightNow.CX")[0];
        IntPtr ptrFF = proc.MainWindowHandle;
        //Get a handle for the Calculator Application main window
        if (rightNowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Could Not Find Right Now");
            return;
        }
        SetForegroundWindow(rightNowHandle); //Activate Handle By Class
        //SetForegroundWindow(ptrFF); //Activate Handle By Process
        SendKeys.SendWait("{F1}");
    }
```

And here is what I pull with Window Spy

[image: Window Spy Info]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: instead of rightNowHandle try to use ptrFF which you aren't using at all.

Comment: @Cistoran Is your process a 32-bit process and the RighNow.CX.exe proccess a 64-bit process?

Comment: @JonathanCarroll They're both 32-bit processes on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: @Gusman neither of them work. I tried both.

Comment: Maybe you don't have the right class/name, A lot time ago I usually played with those api's and sometimes is a nightmare to find the rght window (maybe it's a window inside a window, or it has a proxy window, etc etc). Try one thing, compare the handle you got to the handle given by Spy++, if it's the same then you are sure that's not the right class/name.

Comment: @Gusman Looks like I ended up figuring out my issue... SetForegroundWindow doesn't restore the window if it's minimized.

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my issue.

`SetForegroundWindow` does not show the application if it's minimized, which is what I was anticipating.

Next I used [Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/), to send the input instead of SendKeys.

Here's the code I ended up using.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

private void debugButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //GetProcess by Class
        IntPtr rightNowHandle = FindWindow("WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.24dc298_r17_ad2", null);
        //Get Handle by Process
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("RightNow.CX")[0];
        IntPtr ptrFF = proc.MainWindowHandle;
        //Get a handle for the Calculator Application main window
        if (rightNowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Could Not Find Right Now");
            return;
        }
        SetForegroundWindow(ptrFF); //Activate Handle By Process
        ShowWindow(ptrFF, SW_RESTORE); //Maximizes Window in case it was minimized.
        //SetForegroundWindow(rightNowHandle); //Activate Handle By Class
        InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.LMENU, VirtualKeyCode.VK_A); //Send Left Alt + A
    }
```